# hbase table namespace manager not ready yet

Tags: hbase

The error message:
Error: java.io.IOException: Table Namespace Manager not ready yet, try again latter at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.getNamespaceDesc.java:3092)

Config:
My Config files for env and xml are below.
I followed the install instructions precisely from Hortonworks manual install. I want to have this run in pseudo-mode on localhost. Hbase status is sat, but the error is generated by:
hbase> create 'SALES', 'customer', 'address'

Troubleshoot:
I have shutdown Hbase and ZK. Reviewed the config files line by line. Tried several variations based on recommendations from hbase.apache.com. The same error. I then removed the hdfs file system /hbase and used zkcli to remove the directory in zk. I check at it is writing to both ZK and HDFS. Shutdown the cluster and all deamons. I even rebooted in case this was a memory leak of some sort. I am still in the same state. I understand it is trying to create a meta entry for the table in some location. Some how this table is not being access. I am presuming this meta table is on ZK. Is this true? How should I proceed?

Files:
           
             hbase.rootdir
             hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase

```
   <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
   </property>

   <property>
     <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
     <value>localhost</value>
   </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
      <value>/var/data/zookeeper</value>
    </property>
```

```
 # The java implementation to use. Java 1.7 required.
 export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}

 "hbase-env.sh" 82L, 3834C
#
 # export HBASE_JMX_BASE="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-     Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS="-Xmx2048m"
export HBASE_REGIONSERVER_OPTS="-Xmn200m -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m"
# export HBASE_THRIFT_OPTS="$HBASE_JMX_BASE 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10103"
# export HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_OPTS="$HBASE_JMX_BASE 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10104"

# File naming hosts on which HRegionServers will run.
  $HBASE_HOME/conf/regionservers by default.
 export HBASE_REGIONSERVERS=${HBASE_CONF_DIR}/regionservers

# Extra ssh options. Empty by default.
# export HBASE_SSH_OPTS="-o ConnectTimeout=1 -o SendEnv=HBASE_CONF_DIR"

# Where log files are stored. $HBASE_HOME/logs by default.
  export HBASE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/hbase

# A string representing this instance of hbase. $USER by default.
# export HBASE_IDENT_STRING=$USER

# The scheduling priority for daemon processes. See 'man nice'.
# export HBASE_NICENESS=10

# The directory where pid files are stored. /tmp by default.
export HBASE_PID_DIR=/var/run/hbase

# Seconds to sleep between slave commands. Unset by default. This
# can be useful in large clusters, where, e.g., slave rsyncs can
# otherwise arrive faster than the master can service them.
# export HBASE_SLAVE_SLEEP=0.1

 # Tell HBase whether it should manage it's own instance of Zookeeper or not.
  export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now corrected. There are two answers. One is subtle and the other a misconfiguration.

When creating a table the HBase master needs to write out to a table space. This space is on the region server. My region server file was empty. No server identified. When I ran sudo /etc/init.d/hue start the region server deamon would not start and thus the error. By adding localhost to this file the problem resolved.

Additionally, I interrupted the problem to mean the HBase master was having a problem writing to the ZooKeeper file space. So I kept adding parameters to gain connectivity. I have now backed all of these out.

I found an excellent description of how this works in the PackT book on HBase. This gave me the insight to fix this correctly.